# Google CalDAV PROPFIND response

Tags: carddav

We are coding Plugins for Roundcube.

We noticed that Google stopped to return vcard URL's on a PROPFIND request to ...

```
https://google.com/m8/carddav/principals/__uids__/user%40gmail.com/lists/default/
```

Due to this issue Thunderbird/SoGo stopped sync'ing contacts too.

Issue was reported first time 03/28/2013.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the URL you're sending the requests to is valid anymore. You should use the one, which can be discovered by sending a `PROPFIND` to `https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav`, which at this moment is:

> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/your@gmail.com/lists/default
> ```